# Get the last line of Vim terminal output

Tags: terminal-buffer, vim9script

I use Vim for editing DocBook files. I created several functions that manipulate the text in the buffer. For example to build a PDF from the source using an external command. I run these functions asynchronously in a separate Vim terminal buffer. I need to capture the last line of the terminal buffer after the build PDF process finishes because it is the path to the target PDF file. The process is following:

```
let term_buf_no = s:RunCmdTerm(cmd, 'term_name', 'exit_cb')
```

The above command runs `s:RunCmdTerm` function and passes the `cmd` which is the actual command to be run (building PDF) + a callback function `exit_cb`

the `RunCmdTerm` function runs `cmd` in a terminal buffer like this:

```
let term_buf_no = term_start(cmd, {'term_name': name, 'term_rows': 10, 'exit_cb': exit_cb})
```

Everything works fine, but when I want to capture the last line of the terminal buffer inside the `exit_cb` function with:

```
let target_dir = getbufline(term_buf_no, '$')[0]
```

it captures earlier lines from the output but never the last one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need a terminal? If you just want to run the command to extract the last line, you can use [`systemlist()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#systemlist%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

The `term_wait(150)` function before reading the last line of the terminal buffer output solved it :-)

Comment: Maybe could you post a very light version of the entire solution such that the problem and its solution could be reproduced?

Comment: So you were calling `exit_cb` before the terminal process finish?